# python uninstall and update packages

Tags: python

I want to update all eggs and uninstall some I installed using easy_install.

How could I do that?

I've been looking for ways of updating/removing eggs and I find out that it's just one big crap - there is no way to do that other than writing my own software for that. Is that really so great crap that I cannot update/remove all?

Comment: I think you mean "eggs".

Comment: Gem's are in Ruby. Here are packages or eggs.

Comment: heh, thanks for the remarks. Just a stupid mistake, I use too many languages at the same time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this post](http://pyinsci.blogspot.com/2007/07/updating-all-your-eggs.html).

Comment: As I know distutil doesn't have uninstall command http://bugs.python.org/issue4673

Comment: Yep, what a crap... this issue is know for 2 years now, nobody fixed that for 2 years. I really even don't want to think about other basic issues, that are not fixed for such a long time.

Comment: @Simon: If you come up with a good fix, they will probably happily apply it.

Comment: @Steve right, but I've got my work to do, I don't have enough time to improve everything, if a tool doesn't work, I think I won't use it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko you know that you can edit and improve this answer instead of flagged it to be removed? The answer seems ok, so why removing it?